# Why does *time.Time display as the timestamp instead of memory location?

Tags: go

I've been working on a hobby project and have gotten to the point where I need to differentiate between an initialized zero value, and an intentional zero value for any partial update capable requests. After a lot of reading, I went with the route of making all of my incoming struct fields pointers. Since pointers initialize to nil, and the JSON marshaller binds zero values, it lets me make that distinguishment. I started sending some API requests over, and was seeing what I expect at first, results looking like:

```
{0xc00058e240 <nil>}
```

When I added a time.Time field to the struct though, and sent a timestamp over, I see this:

```
{0xc0004060d0 <nil> 2004-10-16 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}
```

I would have expected the timestamp to also be a pointer to some memory location. I tested a little more with the methods below, and it still prints a timestamp. I was under the impression if you tried to use `*variable` in an operation, it would throw an error for you. The code below works as expected, so it's like time.Time is a pointer even though it prints right from the struct in its normal format.

```
type updateTestRequest struct {
    TestString    *string    `json:"test_string" binding:"alphanum"`
    TestName   *string    `json:"test_name,omitempty"`
    TestTime *time.Time `json:"test_time" time_format:"2006-01-02" binding:"required"`
}

func (server *Server) updateTest(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var req updateUserRequest
    if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&req); err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, errorResponse(err))
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", req)
    if req.TestTime != nil {
        fmt.Printf("value: '%v'", *req.TestTime)
    } else {
        println("it was nil.")
    }
    
}

{
    "test_string":"Testing",
    "first_name": "",
    "date_of_birth": "2004-10-16T00:00:00.00Z"
}
```

I'm still pretty new to Golang, so it could be my misunderstanding of the language. Why does timestamp not print out as a memory address like the other pointers?

Comment: fmt.Printf("%p", req)

Comment: Rule of thumb: Stop expecting stuff and just read the documentation carefully. This often is much faster than guessing, experimenting and asking on SO.

Comment: @Volker Yet there is nothing in the documentation that I can find that says *time.Time will not print the pointer value. The documentation explicitly states that %v will print in default format. To someone who is new to golang, reads that, and sees that every other value prints the memory address, it's understandable how it would be confusing. Here, I'll even post a url for you to read instead of just stating that it's somewhere in the many pages of documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/fmt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [time package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.String) shows that time.Time has a `String() string` method.  Because the pointer receiver method set includes the value receiver methods, a *time.Time also has a `String() string` method.

The [fmt package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#hdr-Printing) says:

> If the format (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) is valid for a string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply:

> 5. If an operand implements method `String() string`, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

It follows that the *time.Time is displayed using the result of the time's String() method.

Comment: thanks for your answer. :) I've only been working with Go for a few months now, so I'm sorry if I have this confused. The %v is supposed to print values in their default format, but if a variable you're calling implements the String() method, it will use that and dereference it / print the value too?

Comment: just read the documentation @JDev

Comment: @erik258 You think I would be asking here, if I could find documentation that makes sense to me? So please, point me to a good piece of documentation that clearly describes what I am asking here. I am definitely open to it, and would much prefer it. I just can't find it.

Usually, when the documentation doesn't make sense to me, having it explained another way will help... hence the post here.

Comment: @JDev The documentation lists special formatting considerations that apply to operands that implement certain interfaces. The answer quotes the special consideration that applies to `*time.Time`.   The time's String() method is called and the %v format is applied to the result of that call.

Comment: I think I understand now. I was under the impression that struct field pointers had to be dereferenced before making use of their method implementations. 

Thank you bruford, and @CeriseLimón for the helpful responses. :)

Comment: @JDev The [method set](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_sets) of a type determines the methods that can be called on an operand of that type.   The method set of a pointer to a defined type T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yeah, I've only been working with go for ~3 months, but it makes sense now. I've never worked with a language that used pointers before this. I have almost exclusively worked with Java in my professional and personal life.

So pointers in general have some aspects around them that catch me off guard. I was thinking of a pointer as ONLY the address to the value, and not making the correlation that the pointer was still able to use its method sets.

Thanks for the additional link, I saved it off for future reference. It helped clear up a couple other points for me as well. :)